# shell script for checking files at remote scp sever using ssh

Tags: unix, ssh

I am checking files at remote sever in /temp directory and storing the count of the files in a temp files and doing scp to local sever.
When I am running below command on console, its running file but its not working in shell script.

```
ssh id@$remote_sever
cd /temp
ls  *.txt | wc -l > /temp/temp.txt
scp /temp/temp.txt infa_id@local_sever:/TEMP
exit
```

Comment: /temp/temp.tx sure not a typo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a temporary file on the other machine. You can execute the command via SSH and then store the result locally:

```
ssh id@remote_server 'ls /temp/*txt | wc -l' > /TEMP/temp.txt
```